# append dataframe in to existing dataframe with condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conditional-statements, match

My goal now I got two dataset and I want to clean them and write into an existing excel file without overwriting.

Since I will repeat this proces several times and it has a column with date, I want to match the dataset with the newest part and add only the newest into the excel file. Since this should take the least amount of time.

For example, today I can extract data from 2-02 to 2-19 but tomorrow I will also extract data from 2-02 to 2-20, but then I only want write 2-20 into that excel.

But I just don't have any ideas about how to achieve that. Do you guys have any ideas about how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the existing Excel-file into a dataframe `df1`. Say your updated dataset is called `df2`, you can filter your new dataset to dates bigger than the last date in `df1`.

Since I don't know what your datasets look like, I assume there is a column `'Date'` or something similar, which is also formatted in pandas as datetime.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(<your excel file>)

df2_new = df2[df2['Date'] > df1['Date'].max()] # filter df2
df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2_new]) # Concat new part with old part
df_new.to_excel(<your excel file>) # Export back to Excel-file
```

This is probably the easiest way using (just) Pandas. If the dataset/Excel-file gets very big, it might be more efficient to update the existing Excel-file bij adding the new rows with `Excelwriter` or similar package.

Comment: yeah i am doing the same way